# Unable to fetch and draw lengthy php reports

Tags: php, mysql

I moved my application from one server to another. I can't generate lengthy report after I moved to my new server. My reports are generating by running php code, Just writing mysql result set out put to HTML table. Some reports have more than 90 thousand records. But it always showing 39 thousand records only. My max execution time and post max size are good enough. Below I am posting my php.ini settings. Any help will be thankful.

```
post_max_size=300M
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = On
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Comment: If the server environment is the only thing that has changed it would be helpful if you included details of the original and new environments.

Comment: Both server has same configuration php 5.4 ,mysql . php.ini same as I shared

Comment: `max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 1000` try increasing these values

Comment: My mysql_num_rows showing more than 90 thousand records, But while looping through the records its loops upto 39 thousands only. I think something related to mysql configuration

Comment: @chrisis If i fetch a few column, Its fetching and PHP drawing full rows. But If I select full column(more than 38 column ) its fetching half. Something related to mysql mem to hold sql result